# Docusign login advice

Tags: docusignapi

In my testing, I used a web proxy to get thru the firewall here so I could send envelopes. Now I will no longer be using the proxy. Do I need to log in for each web request ( like getting the templates, creating an envelope, etc )? The way we will use docusign is like this: a client consultant will see 3 documents that need to be sent to user X. So they will create an envelope with the 3 documents and send it out. They only need to connect to Docusign for a few rest calls and then they're done. The client consultants will connect to Docusign a few times a day, maybe no times a day if there are no documents to send. I'm assuming that I should go out and see if I can connect to Docusign without a problem before attempting to send out an envelope. What workflow are other people using in similar situations?  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I think a short answer here is that every API call you make requires a form of authentication provided, whether it is username/password or an oauth token passed in the appropriate x-header in your API request. I doubt your proxy was adding this on your behalf, so IMO I do not see what you will be gaining/losing by removing the proxy.

Comment: Luis is correct. There is no "login" or "sessions" with the API. Each API call includes authentication information.